# Duplicate key when inserting with hibernate into inherited classes

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

Hello I hope you can help me, I have a problem with the inserts in hibernate.
First I have a Person class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_card", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(13)")
    private String idCard;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    private String lastName;
}
```

And I have two classes plus one provider.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "providers")
public class Provider extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Provider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Customer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Customer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

What happens is that I insert a provider and there is no problem, just like when inserting a client there is no problem, what happens is that when I already insert a person as a client I can no longer insert them as a supplier I get that the key.

What happens is that a person can be a customer and a supplier or an employee at the same time.

ER Diagram
[image]

Comment: Are `Client` and `Supplier` separate entities?  Within the described hierarchy you need to have duplicate enries if the same person is a client, customer, and supplier.  As this does not look good, you may want to replace inheritance _is-a_ relationship with _has-role_ relationship: `Person` has `Set<Role>`, `Role: Client, Customer, etc.`

Comment: Edit. Added ER Diagram. Please check it so I have my diagram.